# Seperation of concerns (service and router layer)

Tags: javascript, express, callback, separation-of-concerns

I would like to improve my skills in Node JS. Right now I'm interested in how to cleanly separate the service and router layers of an application so I can avoid something like code duplication.
The `create method` of a user scheme shall serve as an example.

In `UserService.Js` I store the following method for this:

```
function createUser(req, res, next) {

  let user = new User({
    userID: req.body.userID,
    userName: req.body.userName,
    password: req.body.password,
    isAdministrator: req.body.isAdministrator
  });
  user.save().then(function() {
    res.send(user);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

}
```

The following code is stored in `UserRouter.Js`:

```
router.post('/publicUser', userService.createUser)
```

The code works, but the separation of concerns is not respected. **How** do I write the **create function** now with a **callback function** ?

My attempt looks like this:

```
UserService.js  

function createUser() {

  let user = new User
  return user;
}

UserRoute.js    

    router.post('/publicUser',function(req,res,next){
  let newOne=userService.createUser()
  newOne.userID=req.body.userID
  newOne.userName=req.body.userName
  newOne.password=req.body.password
  newOne.isAdministrator=req.body.isAdministrator
  newOne.save().then(function() {
        res.send(newOne);
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })})
```

It works. But does a more elegant way exist ?

Comment: What concerns are you trying to separate?

Comment: The idea is to use the principle of separation of concerns to move the business logic away from the node.js API Routes. So I Don't want to pass the req or res object to the service layer.

Comment: Ok, so just put all what you currently have in `createUser` as the callback to `router.post`, and then move the `user.save()` "business logic" part into a separate function. Do not use extra callbacks. Just have it return the promise.

Comment: Ok, so how would this example looks like ?

Comment: Just like I described? Please [edit] your question to show your attempt, or elaborate on where you are stuck

Comment: I would suggest to pass the `req.body` as a parameter to `createUser`

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code to give you an idea of implementation. You can further enhance as per the complexity and requirements.

**UserRouter.Js**

```
// import service here
router.post('/publicUser', createUser)

async function createUser(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const response = await UserService.createUser(req.body);
        res.send(response); // Enhance 'res' object here and return as per your requirement.
    } catch (error) {
        // log error
        res.status(500).send(''); // Enhance 'res' object here with error and statuscode and return as per your requirement.
    }
}
```

**UserService.Js**

```
async function createUser(body) {
    // check emptiness if any for body and throw proper errors.
    let userModelData = UserModel.getUserInsertPayload(body);
    return UserRepository.save(userModelData);
}
```

**UserRepository.js**

```
// all code related to persistance. This is separate layer.
async function save(user) {
    // Do any enhancement you need over the payload.
    return User.save(user);
}
```

**UserModel.js**

```
// import User here. Create a payload related to User specific requirements.
function getUserInsertPayload(body) {
    return new User({
        userID: req.body.userID,
        userName: req.body.userName,
        password: req.body.password,
        isAdministrator: req.body.isAdministrator
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how do I write the UserService and UserROuter interaction with callbacks ?

Comment: @pawl123 You don't need callbacks

Comment: @Ankur I don't think the `UserService` should interact with the whole `req`uest (and even less, `res` and `next`). Pass only the body from the router.

Comment: Dear @Bergi,  I have just tried to give a very high-level idea. It is purely up to the developer to apply requirements and expertise and achieve the desired result. But I agree and have made changes to my answer. Thanks, cheers!